# How to combine two arrays of different dimension in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I do have two arrays which are (150,1400,1200) and (150,1400). I want to know how to combine these two arrays row and column wise in Python?

Comment: One way to combine the two arrays row-wise is to use the NumPy module's hstack() function. Documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, You need to add one dimension to `b` then  use [`numpy.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

```
a = np.random.rand(150, 1400, 1200)
print('a.shape:',a.shape)
b = np.random.rand(150, 1400)
print('b.shape:',b.shape)
print('b[..., None].shape:',b[..., None].shape)

c = np.concatenate([a, b[..., None]], axis=2)
print('c.shape:',c.shape)
```

Output:

```
a.shape: (150, 1400, 1200)
b.shape: (150, 1400)
b[..., None].shape: (150, 1400, 1)
c.shape: (150, 1400, 1201)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can have a look at the below link to resolve your issue

[Concat two arrays of different dimensions numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700081/concat-two-arrays-of-different-dimensions-numpy)